# How to Split and sum of them & compare condition in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Sample Table

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
S.No        |  Date                     |  Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  1         |  20/10/2015;26/10/2015    |  5000;2000    
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  2         |  15/10/2015;25/10/2015    |  1500;6000
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to Split `Date` and `Amount` and sum of total amount using mysql?

Example

```
    select *,SPLIT_STR(date, ' ', 1) as split_date,
             SPLIT_STR(amount, ' ', 1) as split_amount , sum(split_amount) 
from  
         bill_table having str_to_date(split_date,'%d/%m/%Y') <=20/10/2015'
```

Actually i am expecting the ouptput:

> 20/10/2015 = 5000
>
> 26/10/2015 = 2000
>
> 15/10/2015 = 1500
>
> 25/10/2015  = 6000
>
> Condition <20/10/2015  So (5000+1500) = 6500

Please help me to solve this problem.

Split Value (Array) & Adding sum of them

Comment: Where does the 6500 come from? Your question is unclear what you want

Comment: You are missing the "FROM `table`" statement in your query. Maybe add it? Also, maybe you should split on ";" instead of a whitespace? What is the actual output of this query? Also you are writing `bill_table having ...`. I think you need `bill_table WHERE ...`

Comment: You should really rethink your tables design. A relation 1-N would solve your problem really easy and elegantly

Comment: Agreed with @JorgeCampos, or if you dont want to do that i think you should solve this in PHP. Not in MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL split values to multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample. You can put your Fieldname in:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('20/10/2015;26/10/2015', ';', 1),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX('20/10/2015;26/10/2015', ';', -1);
```